# why Rails 4 production request every time image on heroku?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

[image]

every time Rails 4 request for same image in production which break site performance .

in development mode if once image load then it not requesting and site performance is far than production

any solution to load file just 1 time and picke cache from it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Chrome and have the developer panel open.

Since your screenshot is showing `403 Not Modified` codes, the browser knows that it should use the cached version of the image. But it doesn't.

My guess is that you have the option '**Disable cache (while DevTools is open)**' checked.

With the developer bar open, click the wheel icon in the bottom right. This opens the developer options. Uncheck it or close the devtools to enable caching.